# Mixing two songs very different bpm help

Tags: mixing

Question is : I need some suggestions of how I can create a 124 bpm version of this song while still keeping the same level of energy to match the original track

This song has a bpm of 161 and I will add drums and guira to style it as a bachata remix, however the drum samples I have are of 117,124, bpm. I am more concerned about it having a bachata feel as well as having the bpm around 110-130 anything faster would make dancing to this song in that style difficult.

I have slowed down the original song from 161 to 120 and it doesn't have that same energetic feel. I also can cut the vocals however needed, because they have the vocal only version too.

Help please

Comment: I can't see a question here. Can you clarify what it is you are asking?

Comment: It is a bit unclear, but he's asking how to mix two tracks that have completely different BPMs in a way that maintains the energy of the original at the slower tempo of the rhythm samples. At least, that was my take on it. However, I must weigh in and say that using samples in very different BPMs will make  the track either too slow or too fast, and the energy will either be lost or amped, because the music was not written originally in that way. The sense of flow gets muddled when making something be something else. Remixing is a tough subject, not everything is fit for remixing.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is something that will be very difficult, such a huge bpm difference and difference in styles it's less of a remix and more of a complete re-write of the music. Not that it's not possible, but at that point it's not simply adding one thing to another (a new beat to a tune), you are essentially producing a new "arrangement", and that's not something that's all that easy to address in an answer on a Q and A site.

And while nothing is impossible, I find it very hard to imagine a way to slow down a tune like greased lightning by a whopping 25% (that's a LOT!) and not have it sound dull and lifeless: it's a fast rocknroll tune that's characterised by its tempo. It's like saying "how can I walk but make it feel like I'm running". In this case, you probably can't I'm afraid.